# How to get a single screen shot from photo camera using microcontroller

Tags: camera, photo, microcontroller

Let's imagine that we have any of popular photocameras (like Canon or whatever) installed on a mechanical platform. This platform allows us to accurately adjust camera's lens direction to any interesting object. This platform is controlled from PC via microcontroller board. But we need a feedback from a photocamera - the image which currently appears on camera's display. Obviously, this feedback is required to be sure that the camera looks in a right direction. At the moment I don't know how to get a single shot image from photocamera by a microcontroller.

Could you please recommend me any directions to dig to ? Any recommendations on how to select photo camera (web cameras are not allowed) ? Any tips ?

Thank you in advance =)

Comment: This is probably not the best place for your post.  You might want to try http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: nothing wrong with asking that here at stack overflow, this is a programming question not an electronics question.  Problem is each camera likely has a separate protocol/interface if any.  so you need to go camera by camera.  Start with a camera that has a published protocol, get that working then go on to the next if any.

Answer (score 1):

Dwelch is right, you need to pick a "friendly" camera and work from there - google CHDK for a starter.

You could use the SPI interface of a micro to spoof being an SD card, and accept image data from the camera straight into the micro, but you would probably need quite a fast micro with a fair amount of RAM, especially if you want to do any processing on it.

Other than that, you could sample the camera's AV-output (if it has one), either into the micro or straight into the PC via a USB capture stick (or USB capture stick into micro if you're being a show-off), or maybe interrogate the camera over its USB or (insert name of proprietary port here) IO port.

Getting more hacky (yes, even more!) you could sniff the LCD data bus of the camera and steal the image from that, but that brings all sorts of pain, and tiny, tiny screws.